# Given a list of real numbers. What is a good algorithm to group them together so that the max and the min in the group is smaller than, say 5?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, computer-science

Say I have a list of number like this: 1,100,2,10,3,14,55,101,102,58
I want an algorithm to group them together such that

- The number of groups should be as small as possible
- The difference between maximum number and the minimum number inside one group should be smaller than 5.

In fact the first condition is there just to make the question more rigorous; in my application the numbers are relatively quite separated apart so it would be quite easy at least for a human to see how the group should look like. E.g. On above example, it should obviously be { [1,2,3],[10,14],[55,58],[100,101,102]}

Is there a better algorithm than a double for loop to solve this problem?

Thank you!

Comment: With `The number of group is as small as possible` you mean the sum of a group? It's just sorting and splitting.

Comment: No I mean the how many groups you split should be as small as possible. Otherwise if every element becomes a separate group then condition 2 is fulfilled but that is obviously not what I want. Thanks.

Comment: ah ok. so the sorting in your example output was just random [1,100,3] ... would working too. And `[[1, 100, 2], [10, 3, 14], [55, 101, 102], [58]]` is wrong be the best answer has 2 groups with 2 elements?

Comment: no your answer is wrong because it violates condition 2.. say [1,100,2] the max - min = 100-1 = 99, not smaller than 5.

Comment: ah ok you mean the difference between the max and min inside a group is < 5. I always thought the count

Comment: Thx for pointing out I just edited the question..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can sort all the numbers first, and form the groups greedily in linear time. Say you have the numbers in an array named **arr**, the difference between the maximum and minimum elements(i.e. what you mention to be 5 in the question statement) are called **diff** and indices of the numbers' array, start from 0.

```
n = len(arr)
sortedArr = sorted(arr)
groupStart = 0
groupsFound = [[sortedArr[0]]]
numGroups = 1
for i in range(1, n):
    if sortedArr[i] - sortedArr[groupStart] >= diff:
        groupStart = i
        numGroups += 1
        groupsFound.append([ sortedArr[i] ])
    else:
        groupsFound[numGroups-1].append(sortedArr[i])
```

I think the greedy approach is optimal, in this case, as each number has to be in **some** group. For an array of size n, the complexity of sorting the array is O(nlogn), and the complexity of grouping is O(n), making the overall complexity of the code above **O(nlogn)**.

Answer (score 0):

I think that mathematically this is not well defined. What is a best grouping given, for instance, numbers/elements [1, 8]? Imho you need to define some metric (or whatever kind of scoring function) that is evaluates on the splitting. Is, for instance ( [1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6, 7, 8] ) better than ( [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8])? Are they both equal (which to choose in that case)?

Comment: well in that case I dont mind which one. Rigorously speaking this is indeed necessary, but in my application it is not likely I will get this data. Anyway thanks for the comment!